# htaccess restrict sub dir to my IP not working

Tags: apache

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.x.xx  
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

I have the above in a .hta file in a subdir of my site where I am trying to restrict access to that directory and its subs to ONLY my IP. I have a static IP and I have checked the IP entered is correct, yet it will not allow my IP ...

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the RewriteRule. `RewriteRule . - [F]` will not differentiate between IPs and the rule will always be applied, so regardless of whatever the request is (except for `/`), you will always be forbidden (**[F]**).

---

Update:

If it's a parent's directive, try adding `AllowOverride Limit` to the top of the file (and still removing the RewriteRule)

If there's *still* something that prevents you from overriding parent directory rules, you can do it purely by the RewriteEngine:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx.xx.x.xx$
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

This will add the condition to the forbidden rule that the remote address (the client connecting) *isn't* xx.xx.x.xx, if it is, the condition fails and the rule won't be applied.

Comment: Already tried that. When removed it allows access to everyone. I think

Comment: Already tried that. Problem is this hta is being overridden by allow directives in the root hta so without a rewrite rule it either gets ignored or allows everyone or no one.

Comment: without the rewrite rule the directive does nothing at all. Is there another rule I should be using instead ?

Comment: The override limit didn't work but the new rewrite condition worked a treat ... Thanks!